# OpenCV & Tensorflow - Detecting Objects and drawing boxes around them

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning

Hi so I have a model which I made using Tensorflow & Keras, It works flawlessly when I use it on an image which focuses in on the object.

Like... So:
[image: Single Object]

But, now I'm trying to figure out the best way to take an image of lets say multiple of these objects like this and to detect and draw a box around them:

[image: Multiple Objects]

What i'm trying to achieve:
[image: Goals]

Currently my code consist of loading the model, and using it to predict a screenshot which focuses in on the object.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def grabScreen():
    # img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1078,351,1477,748))
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1,29,1255,793))
    img_np = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return frame

def analyze(frame):
    IMG_SIZE = 200
    img_array = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("v3.model")
    CATEGORIES = ["Tree", "Stump"]

    while True:
        frame = grabScreen()

        prediction = model.predict([analyze(frame)])
        print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])

        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have an idea of how to achieve what i'm trying to do, and that is to divide entire screenshot into parts and then using the model to predict on each part. But isn't this going to be very demanding on my laptop? Surely there has to be a better way to achieve this.

I appreciate every help :) Thanks!

Comment: What's the pre-processing pipeline? Ideally, you should segment the object of interest as clean as possible, before passing it on to the classifier. The idea of dividing the image into Regions of Interest [ROI] is a good strategy. The classifier works like this: it receives the image you and computes features. It then compares these features to those "Ideal ones" (obtained during training) and decides if your input "belongs" to the known class. If you have too much noise in your input you will throw off the classifier.

Comment: @eldesgraciado before training the images, i have them all set to a fixed size and grayscaled. Then i shuffled the training data.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my comment when yours came in. I don't think a grayscale conversion suffices, sadly. The stump has a very distinct color, try using that to find potential ROIs for the classifier.